# SqlDataSource won't retrieve logged in user's data from database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, sqldatasource

I tried retrieving the user's data based on the logged in UserId, but no progress. Any suggestions?

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a reference to the currently logged on user  
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();    

    // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value   
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;   

    // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter     
    e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId; 
}
```

And this is the `SqlDataSource`

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
      ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:NaviConnectionString %>' 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [UserId], [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [UserProfiles] WHERE ([UserId]  = @UserId)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is the `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               DataKFFeyNames="UserId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
               EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." 
               DataKeyNames="UserId">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" SortExpression="UserId" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

There are no data records to display.

[image]

However, when I execute the code in query builder, it works.

So I need to get the `UserId` manually from the database.

[image]

Then go to the query builder then execute then paste the `userid` in to the value of `UserID`.

[image]

Then it displays the correct data based on the `UserId`:

[image]

I also tried changing it to this:

```
  <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Empty" DbType="Guid"></asp:Parameter>
  </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and checking the value of `currentUserId`?

Comment: I Checked if currentUserId works by placing a label called userLabel and added userLabel.Text = currentUserId.ToString(); on Page_Load and it displays the userid correctly on the label when the page loads... so i know that currentUserId isnt the problem.

Comment: I have only used the EntityDataSource, but I believe that you must _either_ set the Type or the DbType but not both. Also, you may want to edit your question and title to reflect that retrieving the UserId is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a break point and see if `currentUserId` is populated. I believe that it is. If so, then retrieving the UserId is not the problem, but instead the problem is setting the parameter value or selecting the data.

I think you need to change the type of your parameter from **string** to **Guid**

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Guid"></asp:Parameter>
</SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change This:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)

{

// Get a reference to the currently logged on user  
   MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();    

// Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value   
Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;   

// Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter     
e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in parameter types there is no guid option. (Also in above codes sql data source has not been set SqlDataSource1_Selecting.) How could it be answer? Just declare parameter name and its ok.

```
<asp:Parameter Name="UserId"></asp:Parameter>
```